# Vue How to send data to server before leaving page?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, dom-events, reload

How do you send data to the server before closing a tab, the browser, or going to another page or reloading the page? I've tried the following, but doesn't work.

```
ready: function() {
        Vue.util.on(window, 'beforeunload', this.save, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Vue2 you might just need to write it differently:

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.sendData)
  },
  methods: {
    sendData() {
      //send the data
    },
  },
```

I think the way you're writing it may have worked in older Vue versions. The above method seems to work for people according to this thread (https://forum.vuejs.org/t/detect-browser-close/5001/6) but it's difficult to create a fiddle to test it as most browsers will ignore an alert in this situation. It shouldn't block your API call though.